# How to load data into Hive table after altering?

Tags: hiveql

I have a table and i have added a new column. How to i put/load data for that new column?

eg:

```
hive> alter table test1 add columns (msg string);


hive> select * from test1;


nancy   1       23      NULL

urmi    2       24      NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no facility to load data only for the new column in hive.. instead we have to load the data again for the whole table load data & Overwrite cluase.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'path'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test1